# Excel report is opening in browser instaed of asking for download in PHP

Tags: php, header, mime-types

I have moved my server from shared to dedicated one. In shared server my excell report is working fine and asking for download, Which is created by PHP. I have given following header

```
 header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'")                 ;
 header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=MBQ_report.xls");
 header("Expires: 0")                                                       ;
 header("cache-control:just-revalidate,post-check:0, pre-check:0")          ;
header("Pragma: public")
```

In my new server Excell report is opening in browser itself, Not asking for download. Any one please help me to solve the issue. May I know the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

in order to do this change **inline** to **attachment**.

Instead of `header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=MBQ_report.xls");` put `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MBQ_report.xls");`

Did it work ?

Comment: Tested, But not working. I am looking for some configuration change, don't want to change all my php file

Comment: Could you share some server configuration please? Eg. apache or IIS, version of PHP ?

Comment: Apache/2.4.25 and PHP 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the browser settings sometimes, it might be configured to download xls files, or open them directly if xls is a known file extension to the browser. But you have configured to open it and not prompt for download so..

change this

`header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=MBQ_report.xls");`

to this

`header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MBQ_report.xls");`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

> The first parameter in the HTTP context is either inline (default value, indicating it can be display inside the Web page, or as the Web page) or attachment (indicating it should be downloaded; most browsers presenting a 'Save as' dialog, prefilled with the value of the filename parameters if present

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with .htaccess then.

```
   <Files *.xls*>
        ForceType application/vnd.ms-excel
        Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    </Files>
```

OR this

```
<FilesMatch "\.(xls|xlsx)$">
  ForceType application/vnd.ms-excel
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```